# Is Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework still required in PowerShell?

Tags: wpf, powershell, add-type

I have the following PowerShell code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
[xml]$Form  = "<XAML window definition here>"
$NR = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $Form)
$Win = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($NR)
$Win.ShowDialog()
```

If I comment out the very first `Add-Type` statement, the script still works and displays the window UI.

The above script is from a training course dated 2016.  I am wondering whether the `Add-Type` statement is no longer required due to changes in PowerShell since?  Is the assembly in question included by default in the PowerShell environment?  I tested using both ISE and VS Code, on Windows 10.

Comment: `[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]` Require the `PresentationFramework` Assembly... it's not loaded by default

Comment: @Avshalom But why does it still work with the `Add-Type` commented out?

Comment: what powershell version you're using?

Comment: @Avshalom `5.1.19041.1`.

Comment: start a new powershell window and check what assemblies are already loaded: `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | ? Location | Select Name, Location, Version`

Comment: Maybe there is a profile entry somewhere that is adding a module or assembly.

Comment: @Avshalom Thanks.  I rand the command and it listed 18 assemblies, did not include the PresentationFoundation.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see for yourself? :)

Comment: @TanveerBadar Try what?

Comment: What you answered already. I meant you could remove that line in question and see for yourself what happens if you run the script.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Not sure what you mean.  I said above that I already commented out the line.

Comment: Apparently the *PresentationFramework* is not available until the *GetTypes* method has been executed, so in order to do that we have to add the `-PassThru` like this: `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework -PassThru | Out-Null`. 
This also happens when you type a `TAB` for command completion. 
See [discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16054).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from [Avshalom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4568320/avshalom), I was able to figure this out: After an initial call to `Add-Type` in a fresh PowerShell session, the assembly stays resident.  This is why I was able to comment out the statement and still have it work.

But when that session is torn down and a new session is started, the assembly is no longer resident, and the corresponding `Add-Type` is still required.  Otherwise, the following error will be thrown:

> Unable to find type [Windows.Markup.XamlReader].

Following the single `Add-Type` statement in question, the assemblies shown below were all loaded into the session:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Management\v4.0_3.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero2\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0
```